# How to make webbrowser component default to firefox

Tags: vb.net

I am making an app that opens up a website using the WebBrowser Control. Thing is, by doing research i found out that the default is IE / Edge. The OS is windows 10 and so the browser is Edge. When the site loads, it spazzes out and doesnt work as it should! On chrome and firefox it works a charm.

I need a way to change the default browser from Edge to Firefox?

I did my research and found different solutions but they dont work for me. The one i thought would work best is located here: http://thebot.net/threads/vb-net-how-to-make-a-firefox-webbrowser.142359/

When doing so, i would receive an error stating down the lines.. Version issue? <-- Cant remember exact error. But didnt work.

I then tried the `Browse With..` idea but i cant locate this option.. Anywhere!

Please supply as much information to try get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Version? Im running VS 2012, with the latest update as far as i am aware.

Comment: I don't currently have VS2012 installed, but I believe you can right-click on your page and in the options there will be "Browser with..."

Comment: Another thing that confused me is were people would say page? I dont have any .html .asp etc, im using the built in web browser component and its on my form. I then have the URL value in props, pointed towards my designated site. With that said, could you go into specifics? Thanks!